# How to install memcached module for php@7.1 on MacOS High Sierra?

Tags: php, macos, memcached, macos-high-sierra

I have the issue installing a memcached's module for php 7.1. I use MacOS High Sierra and php@7.1 installing using homebrew. During the installation of memcached module for php using command

> pecl install memcached

I received the errors:

> checking for zlib location... configure: error: memcached support
>   requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir= to specify the prefix where
>   ZLIB headers and library are located ERROR:
>   `/private/tmp/pear/install/memcached/configure
>   --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/php-config --with-libmemcached-dir' failed

But I have installed zlib. I can't find a way how to install memcached module after the changes in homebrew repository.

Answer (score 43):

1. `pecl bundle memcached`
2. Change to the directory it output
3. `phpize`
4. Make sure libmemcached and zlib are installed (`brew install libmemcached zlib`)
5. Get the zlib directory (`brew list zlib`)
6. `./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/` (replace the zlib path with the one from the previous command)
7. `make`
8. `make install`
9. Add the extension line in your php.ini file (ex. change the paths to match what make install output.  I added this to my `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d` directory in a file called ext-memcached.ini

`[memcached]
extension=memcached.so`

10. Verify you installed the module `php -m` should show you memcached in the outputted list

Comment: Thanks! Your answer saved me tonight.

Comment: Thanks! Works as of May 2019 on PHP7.0

Comment: This continues to work across versions of php, I tested most recently with php 7.3.7.  Just make sure to edit your paths accordingly. The php path for 7.3 (I believe whatever the "current" version is) seems to be /usr/local/Cellar/php with the version under that.  That will be where your extension path is set to in step 8.

Comment: To find your php conf.d file, just `php -i | grep php.ini` and use the first path.Mine was `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3` and cd into conf.d

Comment: Somehow my phpinfo(); did not want to update to memcached even though php -m worked, so I tried this [tutoral](https://grrr.tech/posts/installing-homebrew-php-extensions-with-pecl/) and uninstalled everything. Works perfect now

Comment: I get `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`. I am dying.

Comment: After make install you can just use:

extension=memcached.so
instead of specyfing full path.

Comment: Thanks so much, this still works in 2021 on M1 Apple Silicon / Big Sur. For me, the `Cellar` directory was in `/opt/homebrew/` and the `conf.d` directory is in`/opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use env variable `PHP_ZLIB_DIR` to tell it where zlib is.

```
PHP_ZLIB_DIR=/usr/local/opt/zlib pecl install memcached
```

Full installation.

```
brew install zlib
yes no | PHP_ZLIB_DIR=$(brew --prefix zlib) pecl install memcached
```

Comment: thank you so much you have save me at last. 

trying to fixing this issue since last 4/5hr

Answer (score 1):

To install memcached prerequisite

- Install pkg-config and zlib using `brew install pkg-config zlib`
- Check Php Version for which you installing should be linked. `php -v` tells you which php version is active for cli.
- `pecl config-get ext_dir` will tell you which version configuration files are set.
- Get configuration path for zlib that is required while installing `brew list zlib`
  Install using `sudo pecl install memcached`
  While installing it will ask `zlib directory [no] :` in that paste zlib configuration path  `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11` example `zlib directory [no] : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11`

Restart your php and nginx/apache2
`brew services restart php@7.2`
`brew services restart nginx`
`brew services restart apache2`

You can check extension is installed or not by using `php -m`.

Note : Am using `MacPro M1 silicon chip` notebook. Installed using `homebrew`. struggle a lot to fix this issue.