# How to load memcached on PHP in Mac OS X Catalina?

Tags: php, macos, memcached, macos-catalina

I have tried virtually everything I could for the last 3 hours. I just don't seem to get it to load on PHP. I was able to install it via `brew install memcached` and successfully make run it as a background service via `memcached -d`. But that's not really what I am looking for.

I am looking at loading it as one of my PHP modules. Running `php -m` on the terminal does not list `memcached` on it at all. Neither looking at `phpinfo()` or `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` on runtime gave me any luck. I am trying to officially access it in my project via something like `extension_loaded('memcached')`, of course, this returns a falsy value atm.

I have tried solutions like below:

[How to install memcached module for php@7.1 on MacOS High Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601476/how-to-install-memcached-module-for-php7-1-on-macos-high-sierra)

https://donatstudios.com/OS-X-Mavericks-Memcached-PHP-Extension-Installation

[Can I install the memcached PHP extension with PECL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683864/can-i-install-the-memcached-php-extension-with-pecl)

Most of the solutions are similar to the above linked. Unfortunately, this isn't working for me because of an issue similar to this:

[Unable to use PHPIZE after update to MacOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592548/unable-to-use-phpize-after-update-to-macos-mojave/52612102#comment103708853_52612102)

I also get below error when executing a `make` command:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

And the below error when running `./configure`

> checking for session includes... configure: error: Cannot find
>   php_session.h

Meanwhile, I also cannot attempt an install via `pecl install memcached` due to the error below:

> configuration download directory "/tmp/pear/install" is not writeable.
>   Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this
>   warning

Basically everything just doesn't work. And honestly, I didn't even know how to start writing this question, so I'm just kinda throwing everything in here.

It doesn't help that there are no recent discussions about installing memcached on PHP since Catalina. A lot of resources are just 5 years old and that's not a good sign, a number of them aren't even valid solutions anymore.

I am losing my mind. Why this thing is so complicated to configure is beyond my comprehension. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to find a solution after 2 working days. What you should do is move away from using built-in Apache/PHP from macOS and use the ones from Homebrew.

Here are the descriptive step-by-step procedure I did:

1) Unload the built-in Apache.

2) Install a new Apache from Homebrew via `brew install httpd` and then run the service

3) Install PHP via `brew install php`

4) Configure httpd.conf from `/usr/local/etc/httpd/`, including loading Homebrew PHP module, mod_rewrite, setting up DirectoryIndex, ServerName, default Listen port, etc.

4.1) If you are using virtual hosts, set this up on `/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/`

5) Configure ~/.bash_profile to use the new PHP version (test via `php -v` or `which php`)

6) Install PEAR

7) Install memcached via PEAR

---

I have compiled a list of links that you can use:

**Apache & PHP Installation**

https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-macos-homebrew/

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions

https://gist.github.com/DragonBe/0faebe58deced34744953e3bf6afbec7

Follow `brew info php` to configure Homebrew PHP to Homebrew Apache

**Configure bash profile to use homebrew php by default**

[PHP --version shown incorrectly on osX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096930/php-version-shown-incorrectly-on-osx)
[How to use the php that brew installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed)

**Install PEAR and configure**

https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/install-pear-pecl-mac

**Install memcached via PEAR**

`pecl install memcached` then follow instructions

Or

[How to install memcached module for php@7.1 on MacOS High Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601476/how-to-install-memcached-module-for-php7-1-on-macos-high-sierra)

https://donatstudios.com/OS-X-Mavericks-Memcached-PHP-Extension-Installation

[Can I install the memcached PHP extension with PECL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683864/can-i-install-the-memcached-php-extension-with-pecl)

Comment: Hi Abana! I'm having the same problems but with another extension. Could you confirm if this solution it's letting you install the gRPC extension?

Comment: Hi @LuisRivera, unfortunately I do not have any installed python dev environment so I cannot confirm if I could install the extension. Looking at the docs of this gRPC extension I don't think the installation procedures are similar, so I'm not sure if this post can help you. BUT i would generally recommend using third party Apache server on your macOS instead of using the default one in order to prevent issues like this.

Answer (score -3):

why don't you try vagrant box. You will get a virtual environment of your choice, install a ubuntu environment in minutes and you can get a LAMP or MEAN / MERN vagrant box ready made.

Steps :

1) Download and install virtualbox.
2) Download and install Vagrant
3) Go to terminal

Check if vagrant is installed or not.

> vagrant -v

In order to get a ubuntu box spinning up, run these commands.

> vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64

It will download you a ubuntu box in minutes.

> vagrant up
>   vagrant ssh

Have a look at vagrant you will enjoy it.

Also there are whole lot of ready to use boxes
[Vagrant boxes](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search)

Documentation : [[Vagrant Document]](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/project_setup.html)

Comment: You can still create a vagrant box for your old code as well